# Pass Arrays form views to template and access them

Tags: python, django

I passed two arrays from views.py to templates. Those arrays are:

```
uploaders = ['mjadidi', 'jaykaron', 'CIDCO']


batchtes = [{'start_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 11, 18, 37, 7, 68000), 'end_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 11, 18, 53, 26, 68000), 'id': 1}, {'start_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 10, 16, 58, 52), 'end_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 10, 20, 38, 35), 'id': 2}, {'start_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 12, 14, 7, 27, 68000), 'end_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 12, 19, 45, 11, 68000), 'id': 3}]
```

What I can do is to access the contents like

```
    {% for batch in batches %}
        {{ batch.id }}
    {% endfor %}
```

or

```
     {{ uploaders.1 }}
```

How can I access the uploader for the specific batch?
It should be something like:

```
    {% for batch in batches %}
        {{ uploaders.(batch.id) }} //Needs help here
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Even if you could use this syntax in the template, it still wouldn't help you, because you don't have a dict of dicts, you have a list of dicts.

Comment: Piggy backing on @DanielRoseman's comment, you should use the view to organize the template data. You may have to create some simple view model wrapper classes that can do these look-ups for you. Django templates for better or worse are designed to be simple and lacking logic.

Comment: @schillingt Yes, you are right. Thank you!

Comment: I think it is better to zip arrays to one array using `zip(uploaders, batches)` in view, then you can iterate over them.

Answer (score 0):

I think should make custom templatetag:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simpletag()
def get_batch(obj, index, key):
    return obj[index].get(key)
```

In template:

```
{% load yourtemplatetag_name %}
{% get_batch batches 0 start_time %}
```